# Why is jruby giving me this error when installing ruby-debug-ide?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, jruby, ruby-debug

Following is the error logs,

```
$ jruby -S gem install ruby-debug-ide -v '0.4.16'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

"c:/Program Files/jruby-1.6.6/bin/jruby.exe" mkrf_conf.rb

""c:/Program Files/jruby-1.6.6/bin/jruby.exe"" -rubygems c:/Program Files/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR="c:/Program Files/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/
gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib" RUBYLIBDIR="c:/Program Files/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib"
'""c:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Gem files will remain installed in c:/Program Files/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Program Files/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/ext/gem_make.out
```

EDIT: Just tried the same with ruby on rails 3 (instead of JRuby) and I get the same error.

Comment: when you say “ruby on rails 3 (instead of JRuby)”, does it mean you used MRI?

Comment: I do think so. Used the railsinstaller: http://railsinstaller.org/

Answer (score 1):

```
-rubygems c:/Program Files/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake
```

I think you're missing the quotes there... It's why you're getting the error you're getting.